# Spring Boot Form Validation Not Working

Tags: maven, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-form

I am new on **Spring Boot Application**. I have search google to learn Spring Boot Application myself. I have done easiest stuff on **CRUD** for Spring Boot Application but facing one problem regarding **form validation**. I have paste code here with if any one help me to find out problem for form validation.

**User.java**

[image]

**UserController.java**

[image]

**createUser.jsp**

[image]

**pom.xml**

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>demo</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>SpringBootJSP</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.1.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>1.7</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc-portlet</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-couchbase</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: What is the problem you run into? Just posting code without giving details on what is not working won't help.

Comment: Form validation error message are not display on from or jsp page.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
model.addAtrribute("errors", bindingErrors.getAllErrors())
```

is not needed.

As documentation states:

> Any validation violations will automatically be exposed as errors in
>   the BindingResult accessible as a method argument and also renderable
>   in Spring MVC HTML views.

Errors will be exposed automatically to the view.

Comment: You are right, but when I check via bindingResult.hasErrors() it will return me false as result so I am not able to get validation violations.